# Dataset for image classification (trainset = png, validationset = jpg), Is it matter in pytorch?

Tags: python, pytorch, artificial-intelligence, file-conversion, image-classification

guys, I am working on rock scissors paper classification in pytorch

What I have for now, I have a trainset which is consisted of png image file, and a validationset which is consisted of jpg file.

Is it matter using trainset with png image, and validation set with jpg image file?

It takes a lot of time to convert jpg image file to png file during process.

Here's my data set code

```
         # 0: Paper, 1: Rock, 2: Scissors
        self.paper_dir = os.path.join(data_dir,'paper/')
        self.rock_dir = os.path.join(data_dir,'rock/')
        self.scissors_dir = os.path.join(data_dir,'scissors/')
        
        self.transform = transform
    
        lst_paper = os.listdir(self.paper_dir)
        lst_rock = os.listdir(self.rock_dir)
        lst_scissors = os.listdir(self.scissors_dir)
        lst_fist01 = []
        lst_palm01 = []
        lst_swing01 = []
        c = 1
        for f in lst_rock:
            if f.endswith('.png'):
                lst_fist01.append(f)
            else:
                if f.endswith('jpg'):
                    f = Image.open(r'./Dataset3/validation/rock/{}'.format(f))
                    f.save(r'./Dataset3/validation/rock/{}.png'.format(c))
                    c += 1
                    print(f)
                    lst_fist01.append(f)
        
        for f in lst_paper:
            if f.endswith('.png'):
                lst_palm01.append(f)
            else:
                if f.endswith('jpg'):
                    f = Image.open(r'./Dataset3/validation/paper/{}'.format(f))
                    f.save(r'./Dataset3/validation/rock/{}.png'.format(c))    
                    c += 1
                    
                    print(f)
#                     f = Image.open(f)
#                     f.save(f, format='png')
                    lst_palm01.append(f)
        
        for f in lst_scissors:
            if f.endswith('.png'):
                lst_swing01.append(f)
            else:
                if f.endswith('jpg'):
                    f = Image.open(r'./Dataset3/validation/scissors/{}'.format(f))
                    f.save(r'./Dataset3/validation/rock/{}.png'.format(c))
                    c += 1
#                     f = Image.open(f)
                    print(f)
#                     f.save(f, format='png')
                    lst_swing01.append(f)
#         lst_paper = [f for f in lst_paper if f.endswith(".png")]
        
#         lst_rock = [f for f in lst_rock if f.endswith(".png")]
#         lst_scissors = [f for f in lst_scissors if f.endswith(".png")]
        
    
        self.lst_dir = [self.paper_dir] * len(lst_paper) + [self.rock_dir] * len(lst_rock) + [self.scissors_dir] * len(lst_scissors)
        self.lst_prs = natsort.natsorted(lst_paper) + natsort.natsorted(lst_rock) + natsort.natsorted(lst_scissors)
```

This is the best I can think to classify the image.

Is there any best way to do this?

I am sorry that it is bit confused.

The main question that I want to ask is whether I can use train set as png image and validation set as jpg image file.

Does it affect validation accuracy?

Thanks!

Comment: The png/jpg image file is converted to a pixelwise torch tensor before used for training and validation. So it doesnt matter if you use png or jpg.

Comment: Then, can I remove f.endwith(“.png”) parts??